# How to generate a Zebra Puzzle?

Tags: puzzle-creation

[Zebra puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_Puzzle), is a very famous puzzle, where several statements are given regarding a group of people and some of their qualities, and the solver has to deduce all the qualities of each person in the group.

How could one create a new puzzle of that kind? Two requirements should be met:

- The method is applicable for a different number of qualities or "people".
- The method ensures no redundant information is given (that is, removing any of the puzzle sentences would make multiple solutions possible)

Comment: This is not really worth an answer, but I believe the knack is that you should be fluent in *solving* the puzzles, and then you figure out exactly what kind of deductions are fun in you opinion, incorporate one or more of those into your puzzle, try to solve it, see what is missing and add those bits. After that, as the most important bit: sleep on it, and solve the puzzle again after a day or two so that you have forgotten your own thought patterns, and have to work from first principles again.

Comment: I'd reccomend maybe starting from a solution, and working backwards to generate clues. Once you're done, test, test, test! Also, **write down every step and your logic behind it**, and that way when you're test-running it for errors and you get stuck, you can consult your past-self and try and figure out what you were thinking when you made the puzzle.